# In Linux, how can I set a Function globally

Tags: linux, aix, function

In AIX, I have a, FPATH set function, which is globally accessible by just calling the function name. I am trying to replicate this functionality in Linux.
I set the function in $PATH variable, I tried sourcing the script.
But still I get Function not found error.

If I call the function script with absolute path, it works.
example: FmtMg is the function
I place the file in /usr/local/lib directory

```
export $PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/FmtMg
source /usr/local/lib/FmtMg
```

I tried all these above, it still fails. Below is the script to test the function.

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -u # all variables must be set

unset -f FmtMg
autoload FmtMg

GM=`basename $0`

print "Testing FmtMg\n"

FmtMg  -p$GM -l$LINENO -s0 "FmtMg Test Completed."
```

Comment: Note that if you have an executable script `/usr/llocal/lib/FmtMg` then you want `PATH=...:/usr/local/lib`, not `.../usr/local/lib/FmtMg`

Comment: Thank you, I did that but it did not help, I still get Function not found

Answer (score 1):

`FPATH` is a `ksh` feature, which is probably the shell you used on AIX.  I do not believe `bash` works this way, and that's probably the shell you're using on Linux.

If you use `ksh93` on Linux (e.g. `yum install ksh` on CentOS/RedHat; `apt-get install ksh` on Debian) and set your login shell to that, then it will work the same way.  (I recommend `ksh93` and *not* `pdksh` because `pdksh` isn't fully compatible).

On my machine:

```
$ echo ${.sh.version}
Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01

$ grep FPATH ~/.profile 
export FPATH=$HOME/fns
```

Inside that directory I have a function definition for "loop'

```
$ head -3 $FPATH/loop
# A loop function: loop var from to 'commands'
function loop
{
```

Before I use it we can see that `ksh` knows it's a function, but not yet defined

```
$ whence -v loop
loop is an undefined function
```

And when I attempt to use it, `ksh` auto defines it from the `$FPATH` entry

```
$ loop i 1 5 'echo $i'
1
2
3
4
5

$ whence -v loop      
loop is a function
```

Comment: Thank you, the requirement is, I cannot use FPATH anymore. I just want to define the executable in my profile, so when any shell script that references the function executes, the function should be recognized. Now for Linux my profile is set to use ksh and not bash.